# Checking connectivity using powershell for windows update catalog by test-netconnection

Tags: windows, powershell

How to check connectivity of system to https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/home.aspx using test-netconnection in powershell

Comment: seems like icmp is off. Also, this is a very basic question: `Test-NetConnection catalog.update.microsoft.com`.

Comment: Well i wasn't able to check connectivity as icmp is off. is there any other way?

Comment: Maybe an `invoke-webrequest`

Comment: `Test-NetConnection 'catalog.update.microsoft.com' -Port 80` if you have that cmdlet to your disposal, if you don't you can use `System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient`

Comment: I'm curious as to why you are doing this. MSMU is a highly redundant/multi-regional deployment. It's CDN technology, and in the decades I've had to deal with MS update stuff, I've never seen any customer I support globally, do this. Just curious; what is your use case to do this? Lastly, as noted there are other options to `Test-NetConnection`, as shown by Santiago and Abraham. You could also just hit the URL via a script, and if the page loads, then it's live.

Comment: @postanote i have just started to powershell and i wanted to know the reason behind test-netconnection not working for that particular url.

Comment: AbrahamZinala and Santiago Squarzon thanks for the help

Comment: AS for `i have just started to powershell and i wanted to know the reason behind test-netconnection not working for that particular url`. This not just for this URL, as there are ***many sites that actively block partial or any type of automation effort***. You know, in attempts to slow down attacks and the like. Lastly, TC/TNC, et all, only tell you the server is up and the port is open. Not that the site is actually working at all. You have to ask the site to send you a data response after the TC/TNC, etc, to see if it is functional. Online/Live vs operational testing is what that is about.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comments...

Actually, this has nothing to do with Powershell (TC/TNC) at all. It's networking/firewall 101. Had you done ping from cmd.exe, you'd have the same issue. The PS cmdlets are just replacements for cmd.exe executables, for the most part.

So, firstly always look to the help[ file for details on how cmdlet works. Try it from cmd.exe with the associated command and note the results.

PowerShell notwithstanding (as you can do what you are after in a number of ways), for edification per Santiago, Abraham, and my comments; this is what we mean, as there almost always a number of wats to get a result for almost anything you are after.

```
### Checking connectivity using PowerShell for windows update catalog by Test-NetConnection

Test-Connection -ComputerName 'https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com'
# Results
<#
Test-Connection : Testing connection to computer 'https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com' failed: No such host is known
...
#>

Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 'https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com' -CommonTCPPort HTTP
# Results
<#
WARNING: Name resolution of https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com failed


ComputerName   : https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com
RemoteAddress  : 
InterfaceAlias : 
SourceAddress  : 
PingSucceeded  : False
#>

(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com' -UseBasicParsing).StatusCode
# Results
<#
200
#>

(Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com' -UseBasicParsing)
# Results
<#
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" html lang="en">
<head id="defaultHome"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style/catalog.css" /><title>
    Microsoft Update Catalog
</title>
...
#>

Start-Process -FilePath 'https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com' -PassThru
# Results
<#
Page loads
#>

# Or this way, just pull a list of something from the site.
$Criteria     = “IsInstalled=0 and Type=’Software'”
$Searcher     = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Searcher
$SearchResult = $Searcher.Search($Criteria).Updates

foreach ($update in $SearchResult) 
{
    $title   = $update.Title
    $guid    = $update.Identity.UpdateId
    $bundles = $update.BundledUpdates

    foreach($bundledUpdate in $bundles) 
    {
        foreach($content in $bundledUpdate.DownloadContents) 
        {
            if (!$content.IsDeltaCompressedContent) 
            {($url = $content.DownloadUrl)}
        }
    }
}

# Via .Net
($NetPing   = New-Object System.Net.Networkinformation.ping)
# Results
<#
Site Container
---- ---------
#>

$NetPing.Send('https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com').Status

($TcpClient = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient)
# Results
<#
Client              : System.Net.Sockets.Socket
Available           : 0
Connected           : False
ExclusiveAddressUse : False
ReceiveBufferSize   : 65536
SendBufferSize      : 65536
ReceiveTimeout      : 0
SendTimeout         : 0
LingerState         : System.Net.Sockets.LingerOption
NoDelay             : False
#>

$TcpClient.Connect('https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com' ,80)
<#
True If the connection fails, an error message is displayed and the Connected 
property is False.

Exception calling "Connect" with "2" argument(s): "No such host is known"
...
#>
 $Error[0] | 
 Format-List -Force
# Results
<#
Exception             : System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "Connect" with "2" argument(s): "No such host is known" ---> 
                        System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known
                           at System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo(String name)
                           at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)
                           at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress)
                           at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect(String hostname, Int32 port)
                           at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , String , Int32 )
                           --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                           at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.ConvertToMethodInvocationException(Exception exception, Type typeToThrow, String methodName, 
                        Int32 numArgs, MemberInfo memberInfo)
                           at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , String , Int32 )
                           at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
                           at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`4.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
                           at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
TargetObject          : 
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : SocketException
ErrorDetails          : 
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
PipelineIterationInfo : {}
PSMessageDetails      : 

#>

$tcpClient.Connected
# Results
<#
False
#>

<#
Or just use one of the WU modules from the MS powershellgallery.com to deal 
with WU.
#>

Find-Module -Name '*Windows*Update*'
# Results
<#

Version              Name                                Repository           Description                                                                                      
-------              ----                                ----------           -----------                                                                                      
2.2.0.2              PSWindowsUpdate                     PSGallery            This module contain cmdlets to manage Windows Update Client.                                     
2.8.0.0              xWindowsUpdate                      PSGallery            Module with DSC Resources for Windows Update                                                     
0.7.6                WindowsBox.WindowsUpdates           PSGallery            Commands to install Windows Updates on a Windows box                                             
0.3                  GCWindowsUpdate                     PSGallery            Manually enable, run, and disable the Windows Update process and service                         
1.2                  zWindowsUpdate                      PSGallery            Search for, download and install Windows updates on local or remote computers. The module cons...
0.3.2                WindowsUpdateSetting                PSGallery            A set of PowerShell functions to managing Windows Update settings such as pausing, on Windows 10.
0.1.8                WindowsOfflineUpdate                PSGallery            Powershell module for finding, downloading and injecting updates into Windows and Windows Serv...
1.0.2                GetWindowsUpdateApi                 PSGallery            This will help you in fetching microsoft update details, you must create a Microsoft developer..
#>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use since I'm on Linux on my personal laptop, `Test-NetConnection` is not something I can use.

```
Function TestPort {
[cmdletbinding()]
param(
    [parameter(mandatory,valuefrompipeline)]
    [string]$Name,
    [parameter(mandatory)]
    [int[]]$Port
)

    process
    {
        foreach($i in $port)
        {
            try
            {
                $testPort = [System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient]::new()
                $testPort.SendTimeout = 5
                $testPort.Connect($name, $i)
                $result = $testPort.Connected
            }
            catch
            {
                $result = $_.Exception.InnerException.Message
            }
            
            [pscustomobject]@{
                ServerName = $name
                Port = $i
                TestConnection = $result
            }
        }
        
        $testPort.Close()
    }
}

TestPort -Name catalog.update.microsoft.com -port 80,443
TestPort -Name google.com -Port 80,443
TestPort -Name randomnonexistingdomain.com -Port 80,443
```

Remember, always remove the protocols (HTTP / HTTPS) of the sites you're testing and leave only the Domain of the site, if you try this using `catalog.update.microsoft.com/home.aspx` you'll get a `No such host is known` exception because it cannot be resolved by DNS.

Result looks like this:

```
ServerName                   Port        TestConnection
----------                   ----        --------------
catalog.update.microsoft.com   80                  True
catalog.update.microsoft.com  443                  True
google.com                     80                  True
google.com                    443                  True
randomnonexistingdomain.com    80 No such host is known
randomnonexistingdomain.com   443 No such host is known
```